# application should Logout After Browser is closed directly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

In ASP.Net Web application i have to logout after browser is closed directly(All browsers like google chrome,IE and Firefox).Please suggest me any idea.

Comment: have you cnsidered making a ping every 5 seconds

Comment: Trigger the logout in the `beforeunload` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

Answer (score 0):

**Just giving an idea**

If you will add an event listener to the window for example `unload` it will fire for page reloads also. Try doing this and see if it is a good idea.

```
<body onUnload="signOut()">
```

Make `signOut()` function redirect to Account/LogOff which is a built in method of ASP.net.

```
 function signOut() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/LogOff",
        success: function (result) {
        // success
        }
    });
 }
```

Now, when the tab or browser is closed, it will redirect to LogOff method and user will have to login again.